# Default VS2012 Login page - Where's the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

When I create a new VS2012 ASP project for C#, the application automatically creates many forms including Login and Register forms.  I'd like to tweak the logic for the Submit buttons on those pages, but I can't figure out where it's actually doing it.

I found [this resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/06/14/the-new-asp-net-default-web-template-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx), but it doesn't cover much detail.

Can anyone tell me how those Login and Register forms are processing the Submit buttons, and where I can find the code that's running behind the scenes?

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about ASP project and not MVC?

Comment: Yes, this is an ASP Webforms project.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that was the same in 2012, but in 2013 it uses authentication methods from WebMatrix namespace. The default database has plenty of tables for just that.
Not sure if you asked for that but... if you right click on a .aspx file you can choose option "view code" or press F7 when that view is open.

Answer (score 0):

If this is MVC and not webforms(making assumptions here) then most likely you have folders called Models, Views, and Controllers. The controllers handle the interactions. If you are using individual accounts, then you probably have an AccountController under the Controllers folder. The methods in that class correspond to the name of the view that you see. If you see methods with the same name, most likely one will have the [httppost] attribute above it. Thats the one that gets run after submitting the form. The other one is most likely when first visiting the view. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. OP already [confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514688/default-vs2012-login-page-wheres-the-code#comment49104651_30514688) this is a WebForms project.